# How does spaCy's lemmatizer compare to other libraries?

Tags: nlp, spacy, lemmatization

On spaCy's [website](https://spacy.io/usage/facts-figures#speed-comparison) they have some metrics for tagging, tokenizing, and parsing compared to other nlp libraries, but I couldn't find anything about how fast their lemmatizer is. Are there any benchmarks similar to the linked table showing how fast their lemmatizer is in comparison to libraries like nltk, CoreNLP, etc?